# mod_deflate without system zlib

Tags: apache, configure, mod-deflate

I am building Apache `httpd` and I want to build it with the module `mod_deflate`. For this module, I need `zlib`. So I built `zlib` on my own. When calling `./configure` for Apache `httpd`, I call it with this parameters:

```
./configure \
  --enable-deflate \
  ...
```

After the build has finished, I was looking into the `config.log` and it says that also the parameter `--with-system-zlib` was used. Also, when calling `ldd mod_deflate` after the build, I get this output

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffed9ff7000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007fab70ba7000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fab7098b000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fab705bd000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fab70dbd000)
```

But I want to use my own `zlib` version. How can I build Apache `httpd` with my own compiled `zlib` version and not with the system version of `zlib` ?